# Optimising WordPress Woocommerce Import Script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm in the process of doing an auto importer for my Woocommerce store. It's working, but at tremendous expense to resources. It's very slow and slows down the site to the point of no use. Which obviously is a bad start.

Here's how it looks currently:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file( $url );

foreach ( $xml->products->product as $product ) {

    $one_sku = (string)$product->code;
    $productID = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( 'pre-' . $one_sku );

    if ( $productID ) {

        $one_description = (string)$product->description;
        $one_price_wholesale = (string)$product->price->wholesale;
        $one_price_rrp = (string)$product->price->rrp;
        $one_image = (string)$product->imageurl;
        $one_imageName = basename($one_image, ".jpg");


        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $wooproduct = wc_get_product( $productID );

        // Check if product is in draft
        $productStatus = $wooproduct->get_status();

        // Set Product Information.
        if ( $productStatus == 'draft' ) {

            $wooproduct->set_description( $one_description );
            $wooproduct->set_short_description( $one_description );
            $wooproduct->set_regular_price( $one_price_rrp );
            $wooproduct->save();

            // Show updated products
            echo $dataAboutThis;
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

Now I can basically guess why it's slow. It's using the WooComerce functions for `set_description` etc to save new data to the database. And it's probably doing some kind of nefarious SELECT lookup as well as what other tedious functions and crap it needs to run through on the Woo Scripts.

So basically I just wanted an idea of where to start to improve this. I'm guessing using WPDB insert and checking if an update is the direction I need to go. Instead of using the set_whatever WooComerce functions. But what would be the most optimal way to go about inserting into the database. Because a lookup and insert in a foreach loop that can have tens of thousands of products doesn't seem like a great idea to me. I'm Guessing a Join of some kind. Might be the best practice.

It's also worth mentioning that my products already exist at this point. Basically what's happening here is this is new products that got picked up during the stock check updater that was created and added to draft. They only have Stock Amount, Status, title and basic requirements just to get a product on the site. This is looking up those products in draft, matching them to the xml file then updating them. There will always be less in the draft than on the xml file. So I will probably switch the foreach from the xml file to looking up draft products instead at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start by saying you're best off finding and using a tool ready-built to solve this problem, I found many by Googling "woocommerce batch upload products".

You indicate you're sort of going through a draft or "dummy data" process to get some products in the DB, presumably for testing, and then you want to get your full product DB in there, which presumably stops you from using a regular import tool.  I suggest if that's the case, that you delete that data as if it were truly dummy data and then just import your full DB through regular processes.

What's below is a discussion of how to optimize this process if neither of the above approaches is appropriate for you:

---

This type of batch action benefits from running as few database queries as possible, which you've already surmised.  Unless Wordpress/WooCommerce has a ready-built batch import function, you're going to have to build one yourself, which means writing custom queries.

You can also benefit by turning off all of the MySQL indexing checks during your import: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html - and then make sure you turn them back on and perform some re-indexing afterwards.

If you *do* leave indexing on, you can perform an insert/update in a single step by using the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), so long as you have a unique index on some lookup field.  This appears to be the best answer to your question of how to avoid a SELECT in order to choose whether to UPDATE or INSERT, assuming you can't just delete a small amount of incomplete data and treat everything as an INSERT.

You'll also benefit from using [prepared statements or stored procedures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), as it'll shave off milliseconds that add up per query to essentially compile and store your query DB-side.  I don't know if the Wordpress DB abstraction layer supports this - the library it's based on (EZSQL, from way, way back) never used to, and a quick gander at the code doesn't appear to indicate they've ever added it back in.  So, if you want to take advantage of this, you will have to manage the database connection yourself with PDO or mysqli.

The only other optimization I can think of is to batch up a few inserts in a single query, i.e. `INSERT INTO [table] ([column1], [column2], ...) VALUES ([row1-1], [row1-2], ...), ([row2-1], [row2-2], ...);`

Out of all of this, however, the most impactful optimization is probably going to be the first - bypass the models and just run a single insert query for each row.  The others will matter the larger your data set is.

Comment: Hi Great response. Except from the first bit. Anything pre built will be useless to us for many reasons we wont get into. Also thats not dummy data, It's new products. See we allready have a script that auto updates our stock from a simple incrmeental feed. But if a product appears on that feed that we dont currently have on our system appears it creates that product with some simple data jsut to get it up and running and add's it to draft. Which is where this comes in. this will basicly check the draft and update all of the other fields not picked up in the stock check.

Comment: Thanks, for the above, got through the docs. Was exactly what I needed to get on the right path. It's been to long since I messed with Bulk data imports like this and a database.

Comment: Do you think it would be worth starting the import scirpt off with a transient clean up on the DB first?

Comment: Any bulk actions you can complete in a single query, performing that ahead of time can speed things up dramatically